# How to convert wasm back to C++ if I also have the original code

Tags: javascript, c++, tesseract, webassembly, tesseract.js

I'm not the best at explaining this stuff but here I go.

I have a program that uses "tesseract.js" to read an image every second or so.
10% of images have an "Empty page!!" error message, but I don't need or want this error message flooding my otherwise useful error log. I want to remove it from the source code, however, it isn't fired from the easily readable js code...

I assume it is fired from the wasmBinaryFile section, which (if I understand correctly) is a wasm binary compiled version of the original C++ (Tesseract 4.1.1)
In C++ Tesseract, the error message is fired from `\src\textord\colfind.cpp` line 366. If I knew where the equivalent section of the binary code was, I assume that I could remove it.

I know that decompiling wasm to C++ won't necessarily be understandable, but if I did it, would I be able to compare it to the source code for Tesseract and either find the section I need to remove or be able to recompile it for use again?

If so, would someone be able to point me towards a good software to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to revers engineer that code, tesseract is open source, has a github page and you can look at the source code here :
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/main/src/textord/colfind.cpp.
It also means you can use git to get a local copy, modify and compile it. Probably you can even find a way to change tprintf

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that info.
I have absolutely no idea how to compile the C++ into the wasm I need for it to work with tesseract.js but I am sure the info is out there

Comment: yeah like most problems, just take it step by step ;) I never used wasm before, there seems to be a tool chain for it though : https://emscripten.org/docs/introducing_emscripten/about_emscripten.html